# IntelliJ IDEA return null with ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("myfile.xml"));

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've got [this code (link)](https://codeboard.io/projects/78594)

The DOM parser example works fine on codeboard, but I have one error on IntelleJ IDEA that I can't figure out.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:117) at
>   com.pedro.Main.main(Main.java:41)

The next line returns `NULL`:

```
Document document = builder.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("Student.xml"));
```

I have made it work changing `...builder.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream...` to `...builder.parse(new FileInputStream...` and the full path of `Student.xml`:

```
Document document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("G:\JAVA\edxGalileo\DOMParser\src\com\pedro\Student.xml"));
```

What's wrong with Intellij that it does not work?

Comment: it's nothing with idea, just missed resource. check you project layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that `Student.xml` is located in a folder that is marked as a resources root in the IntelliJ IDEA project structure. Then it will be copied to the output directory together with the .class files, and you'll be able to access it using `getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: Thank you for your quicky response. Now it's working fine but everything is a bit confusing for me. At the beginning the XML file was on the same folder that Main.class. I don't find where mark as resource root the "src folder". After I created a new folder called "Resource" and move there "Student.xml". Only on the Out side I see the option to mark as resource root the folder "Resource" but no on the src side. After doing it the code run ok. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. you can create a project and
2. define a source root
3. put the xml into resources folder